# matplotlib behind firewall

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I am unable to install matplotlib behind firewall and there is no way I can set up a proxy because the admins do not provide proxy info at all. My only chance is to download a standalone version. I downloaded a 50mb package in .gz format, extracteda and tried installing using python setup.py install. P.S this is for python3.5 on windows machine.

Any suggestions?

```
============================================================================
Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
            matplotlib: yes [1.5.3]
                python: yes [3.5.0 (v3.5.0:374f501f4567, Sep 13 2015,
                        02:27:37) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]]
              platform: yes [win32]

REQUIRED DEPENDENCIES AND EXTENSIONS
                 numpy: yes [version 1.12.0.dev0+Unknown]
              dateutil: yes [using dateutil version 2.0]
                  pytz: yes [using pytz version 2016.6.1]
                cycler: yes [cycler was not found. pip will attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
               tornado: yes [tornado was not found. It is required for the
                        WebAgg backend. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
             pyparsing: yes [pyparsing was not found. It is required for
                        mathtext support. pip/easy_install may attempt to
                        install it after matplotlib.]
                libagg: yes [pkg-config information for 'libagg' could not
                        be found. Using local copy.]
              freetype: no  [The C/C++ header for freetype (ft2build.h)
                        could not be found.  You may need to install the
                        development package.]
                   png: no  [The C/C++ header for png (png.h) could not be
                        found.  You may need to install the development
                        package.]
                 qhull: yes [pkg-config information for 'qhull' could not be
                        found. Using local copy.]

OPTIONAL SUBPACKAGES
           sample_data: yes [installing]
              toolkits: yes [installing]
                 tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                        your preferred tool to run the test suite / using
                        unittest.mock]
        toolkits_tests: yes [nose 0.11.1 or later is required to run the
                        matplotlib test suite. Please install it with pip or
                        your preferred tool to run the test suite / using
                        unittest.mock]

OPTIONAL BACKEND EXTENSIONS
                macosx: no  [Mac OS-X only]
                qt5agg: no  [PyQt5 not found]
                qt4agg: no  [PySide not found; PyQt4 not found]
               gtk3agg: no  [Requires pygobject to be installed.]
             gtk3cairo: no  [Requires cairocffi or pycairo to be installed.]
                gtkagg: no  [Requires pygtk]
                 tkagg: yes [installing; run-time loading from Python Tcl /
                        Tk]
                 wxagg: no  [requires wxPython]
                   gtk: no  [Requires pygtk]
                   agg: yes [installing]
                 cairo: no  [cairocffi or pycairo not found]
             windowing: yes [installing]

OPTIONAL LATEX DEPENDENCIES
                dvipng: no
           ghostscript: no
                 latex: no
               pdftops: no

OPTIONAL PACKAGE DATA
                  dlls: no  [skipping due to configuration]

============================================================================
                        * The following required packages can not be built:
                        * freetype, png
```

Comment: My best experience on windows 64bit is to simply install [WinPython](https://winpython.github.io) which has most needed modules, including matplotlib and all dependencies on board, and at the same time doesn't mess up your registry or so. Even if you don't want to change your python version, you might still try to use the packages of the respective WinPython distribution (install everything in a temporary folder and copy matplotlib and all dependencies in your python's site-packages folder)

Comment: I did not know that something like this existed. Unfortunately sourceforge is also blocked. Any other source?

Comment: Downloaded the file somehow. Thank you. It worked.